# How to convert Int Hex Array To Char

Tags: c

I have a this type of array:

```c
uint8_t mArray[3] = {0x20,0x40,0x48};
```

But I need to convert this data like this as an integer 20,40,48. It's weird but the sensor sending this data like this. If the sensor wants to send decimal 20, it sends 0x20.

How can I convert `"0x20"` value to as a integer `"20"` in C?

Comment: If `0x20` should become `20`, what should `0x1a` become?

Comment: Is your sensor sending [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) numbers?

Comment: For some reason I suspect that the sensor is sending `"20"` - that is a string, and not `20`

Comment: Sensor sendsonly specific number like 0x40 0x20 0x10 etc @Barmar

Comment: Can you explain what is your input and what you are trying to do with it?

Comment: So... `0b00100000` is really supposed to become `0b00010100`?

Comment: I think the OP wants to convert `0x20` into `"20"` string. This is done easily with `sprintf(dest_string, "%02x", 0x20);` The "sensor" is probably using ASCII encoding for communication.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 3 bytes represent separate numbers 20, 40, 48 and not a bigger number like 204048 or 484020? Please clarify if the data is in fact BCD, or specify the number range. Can you add a reference to the documentation of the sensor? Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive data in BCD format

```
int fromBCD(unsigned char b)
{
    int result = (b & 0x0f) + 10 * (b >> 4);
    return result;
}
```